# Convert ID from query to String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, spring-rest

I have this rest point which is used to return IDs:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return contractService
                .findById(Integer.parseInt(id))
                .map(mapper::toNewDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class ContractNewDTO {
    .....   
    private Integer terminal_id;
    ....
}
```

How I can translate terminal_id into terminal name using second SQL query?

I need something like this:

......map(mapper::toNewDTO)  -> get here terminal_id and make another SQL query to find which name relates to this terminal_id and return the terminal name NOT terminal_id.

Can you give me some advice how to do this?

Comment: What do you actually want to return to the caller? The DTO with the id and the name? Can't your mapper also extract the name from the entity returned by contractService?

Comment: I want to return he DTO with the name. No, I need to do a second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to retrieve terminal_name based on terminal_id.
You have a couple of options:

1) If `terminal_name` is in the same database table as `temrminal_id`, then it should be loaded inside `ContractNewDTO` in your `mapper::toNewDTO` you can implement the conversion logic which uses `terminal_name` instead of `temrminal_id`.

2) If `termminal_name` is in another table (e.g. terminaldetails table) and you will need all the data from that table, then you can create a mapping (e.g. OneToOne joined on the `terminal_id`). [Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) is an excellent writing on how to do OneToOne mapping, from the master himself.

3) Another option is to use @SecondaryTable. Let's say your current entity is TerminalEntity and it has column `terminal_id` and is mapped to table "terminal". The `terminal_name` is in another table "terminaldetails".

What you can do is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal")
@SecondaryTable(name = "terminaldetails")
public class TerminalEntity {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "terminal_id")
     private String terminalId;

     @Column(name = "terminal_name", table = "terminaldetails")
     private String terminalName;
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue by using a second SQL query. Probably it's the most primitive and basic way but I have a fixed time when table page is loaded.